# How to find all object in a database using a script?

Tags: postgresql

Can someone help me with this? I need to find out **all the objects** in a database using a script. The reason why I need this is, I am asked to *change the owner* of all database objects so for that I need to first list down all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're changing every object from role `A` to role `B`, you might like [`REASSIGN OWNED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-reassign-owned.html):

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY A TO B
```

Comment: I am trying below query but it is throwing a syntax error. Am I missing something? reassign owned postgres to "Arun";

Comment: What specific query are you using? Also, what version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: The query I have used is: reassign owned postgres to "Arun"; (using pgadmin). I am using version 8.3

Comment: It's `REASSIGN OWNED BY A TO B`.

Comment: [Please link to the current version of the manual](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual) - or to a matching version if required. v8.2 is outdated. I fixed the link (and the format) - Arun has declared version 8.3.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want [REASSIGN OWNED](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-reassign-owned.html) instead. No need to identify all the objects, just the users.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL (or almost any other RDBMS for that matter), I would recommend to take a look at metadata tables ([system catalog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/catalogs.html)).

Example. You want all tables:

```
db => \d pg_tables
    View "pg_catalog.pg_tables"
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers 
-------------+---------+-----------
 schemaname  | name    | 
 tablename   | name    | 
 tableowner  | name    | 
 tablespace  | name    | 
 hasindexes  | boolean | 
 hasrules    | boolean | 
 hastriggers | boolean | 
db => select tablename from pg_tables;
```

Will get you a list of all tables. You can use a query to build a script to change ownership of the tables you want.

Similarly, you can query other views/tables in the catalog to get other object types (sequences, indexes, you name it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This will give me all tables, but what about other objects like schema, constraints, indexes, triggers etc? Is there any way I can list them?

Comment: I have just updated the answer. Take a look at the link I posted. `pg_class` and/or `pg_index` is probably what you need for indexes. `pg_proc` for triggers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do a pg_dump and pg_restore to create a new database the adding the --no-owner flag on the pg_restore and running the pg_restore as the user you wish to set ownership to should work for this.